# Found weird entries in my work pcs hosts file

Tags: windows, networking, hosts-file

For debugging purposes of an application I edited my hosts-file on my work computer only to find two entries in there that confused me. I know that I did not add those and I don't really understand if they have some deeper meaning.

The entries are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 {somewebsite}.co.uk
127.0.0.1 www.{somewebsite}.co.uk
```

I replaced the actual website with **{somewebsite}** as I don't want to advertise some website on the internet. It is a drone racing site and in no way related to my work at all. I never worked with anything drones so I am really confused what those entries are doing in there.

Now why this actually got me thinking is that I found some network activity showing up in my resource monitor towards exactly this domain. My Firefox is seemingly sending around 8-40 Bytes per second to this domain.

So my question is: Is there any deeper meaning behind those entries? Why is network traffic directed at those domains? Should I be worried or is it just some artifact left (for whatever reason) by some coworker working on this PC before me?

Comment: Did you ask your IT department whenever they added those entries?

Comment: There is no IT department here, we are managing the systems ourselves as we are a small company of softwaredevelopers. Else I would have asked there first :)

Comment: Sometimes it is done by security software or antivirus. This entry is done to protect you from bad websites. After having this entry your browser or any application using internet connection will not be able to connect to that website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning behind those entries is that they are blocked websites for your station.

If you add an entry like 127.0.0.1 msn.com, then msn.com accesses will be redirected locally and you never get to the actual site.

Nothing deeper to this.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know, thanks! So I guess I will just wonder why my coworker found exactly that website blockworthy.

Comment: Putting facebook there does wonders for the less hard-working employees.